# Use \nameref to refer to unnumbered section but allow short titles

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, koma-script

I'd like to refer to an unnumbered `\section*` which in general just makes sense in combination with `\nameref`. However I'd like to define a short title for the section I can refer to, but

```
\section[short title 2]*{Long Title Section Two}\label{sec:Two}
```

or

```
\section*[short title 2]{Long Title Section Two}\label{sec:Two}
```

are not possible.

**Is there any way to refer to an unnumbered section by its short title?**

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}

\section[short title 1]{Long Title Section One}\label{sec:One}

In \cref{sec:One} (\nameref{sec:One}) I refer to \nameref{sec:Two}

\section*{Long Title Section Two}\label{sec:Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should be possible with a hack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps `KOMA` classes provide better ways, but `\@currentlabelname` has to be set (alternativle `\NR@gettitle`) to be effective with `nameref`, i.e. use the optional argument value `#2` as content of `\@currentlabelname`!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
      \latex@@section*{#3}\edef\@currentlabelname{#2}%
    }{%
      \latex@@section*{#3}\edef\@currentlabelname{#3}%
    }%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@section[#2]{#3}
    }{%
      \latex@@section{#3}
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\section[short title 1]{Long Title Section One}\label{sec:One}

In \cref{sec:One} (\nameref{sec:One}) I refer to \nameref{sec:Two}

\section*[Short Title of starred section]{Long Title Section Two}\label{sec:Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where is `latex@@section` defined? I tried looking in the `source2e`-documentation, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @runartrollet: `\let\latex@@section\section` -- it's my style of grabbing the original definition ;-)  -- Since `\section` has moving arguments, I don't need `\LetLtxMacro` here for the sake of the optional argument

Comment: I wonder if there could be a simpler solution by using `\patchcmd` by I don't understand the code suffiently well to try it. It works great also for other levels like subsubsections. Thank you!

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I can extend the code with some explanations, of course, but I don't want to dig into `scrreprt` however. I would agree with you about `\patchcmd` for standard classes, however. Sometimes, it's a choice of how much code you can spare either by patching or by a `\renewcommand`

Answer (score 3):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use `\addsec`. Then it is possible to define a short title in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter}
\section[short title 1]{Long Title Section One}\label{sec:One}
In \cref{sec:One} (\nameref{sec:One}) I refer to \nameref{sec:Two}

\addsec[Short Title Section Two]{Long Title Section Two}\label{sec:Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually very neat, when one just applies the question on parts, chapters and sections. For levels below, your answer unfortunately does not work as there are no commands provided by KOMA-script. As always my minimal example was too minimal, as I actually need a a solution for subsubsections, but didn't thought that that could matter for the MWE. I'm sorry for that.